# Failure Loading XML from String Returned by WCF Service

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, dataset

I have a WCF project that returns a DataSet in XML format. This is in my service contract:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "RunSavedReportByID", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
    DataSet RunSavedReportByID(int savedReportID);
```

I have another project that consumes this service, and I'm trying to get the DataSet back. I call my service like so:

```
strResults = objUtility.GetData("RunSavedReportByID", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { savedReportID = savedReportID }));
```

GetData looks like this:

```
public string GetData(string method, string data)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(externalServiceUrl + method);
            ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
            var postData = encoding.GetBytes(data);

            request.KeepAlive = false;
            request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;

            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.ContentLength = data.Length;

            using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                stream.Write(postData, 0, data.Length);
            }
            using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    if (responseStream != null)
                    {
                        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8))
                        {
                            return reader.ReadToEnd().Trim();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string error = ex.Message;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The string that I get is weird. It looks like this when I save it to a text file:

```
"\"<DataSet><xs:schema id=\\\"NewDataSet\\\" xmlns:xs=\\\"http:\\/\\/www.w3.org\\/2001\\/XMLSchema\\\" xmlns:msdata=\\\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata\\\"><xs:element name=\\\"NewDataSet\\\" msdata:IsDataSet=\\\"true\\\" msdata:UseCurrentLocale=\\\"true\\\"><xs:complexType><xs:choice minOccurs=\\\"0\\\" maxOccurs=\\\"unbounded\\\"><xs:element name=\\\"Table\\\"><xs:complexType><xs:sequence><xs:element name=\\\"InvoiceNo\\\" type=\\\"xs:long\\\" minOccurs=\\\"0\\\"\\/><xs:element name=\\\"GuestID\\\" type=\\\"xs:long\\\" minOccurs=\\\"0\\\"\\/><xs:element name=\\\"ConsumerID\\\" type=\\\"xs:long\\\" minOccurs=\\\"0\\\"\\/><xs:element name=\\\"ContactTitleName\\\" type=\\\"xs:string\\\" minOccurs=\\\"0\\\"\\/><xs:element name=\\\"LastName\\\" type=\\\"xs:string\\\" minOccurs=\\\"0\\\"\\/><xs:element name=\\\"FirstName\\\" type=\\\"xs:string\\\" ... blah blah blah ... \\/NewDataSet><\\/diffgr:diffgram><\\/DataSet>\""
```

Not surprisingly, after I create and XmlDocument and call LoadXml, I get

> Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

If I strip out the first and last quotation marks and unescape the string like so

```
strResults = Regex.Unescape(strResults);
            strResults = strResults.Remove(0, 1);
            strResults = strResults.Remove(strResults.Length - 1, 1);
```

then the XML loads fine, so the XML itself is legit.

So after all this exposition, my questions are

1) Why does the string I get back look so weird? What's up with all the extra quotation marks and backslashes?

2) Is there a better way of getting rid of the bad stuff before loading the XML?

Comment: The `\\` is an escape character - are you sure you're not copying this from a watch window in the debugger?

Comment: That's what I thought at first as well, so I wrote it to file. Still there.

Comment: Do not return data sets from web services http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ReturningDataSetsFromWebServicesIsTheSpawnOfSatanAndRepresentsAllThatIsTrulyEvilInTheWorld.aspx

Comment: Let's just say that it's an "exception to the rule" kind of situation.